# Image bug when scrolling overflow data in datagrid windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, styling

I have a datagridview named dataGridView in my windows form

Here is how I added the columns. Some comment is written in Bahasa Indonesia.

```
        dataGridView.Columns.Clear();

        //Menambah kolom di datagridview
        dataGridView.Columns.Add("id", "Id");
        dataGridView.Columns.Add("nama", "Nama Barang");
        
        DataGridViewImageColumn dgvimgcol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        dgvimgcol.HeaderText = "Gambar Barang";
        dgvimgcol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;

        dataGridView.Columns.Add(dgvimgcol);
        dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 110;

        dataGridView.Columns.Add("harga", "Harga Barang");
        dataGridView.Columns.Add("stok", "Stok Barang");
        dataGridView.Columns.Add("kategori_id", "Kategori");


        dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(248, 142, 123);
        dataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;

        //Agar lebar kolom dapat menyesuaikan panjang / isi data
        dataGridView.Columns["id"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView.Columns["nama"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView.Columns["harga"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView.Columns["stok"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView.Columns["kategori_id"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;

        // Agar user tidak bisa menambah baris maupun mengetik langsung di datagridview
        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
```

As you can see I created a special column called dvimgcol to display images. Then I'm taking data from the database and do itteration to display it on datagridview. Here is the code:

```
            dataGridView.Rows.Clear();

            if (listBarangCabang.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Barang_Cabang bc in listBarangCabang)
                {
                    string path = Path.Combine(FormUtama.location + "\\barang\\", bc.Barang.Path_gambar);
                    //MessageBox.Show(path);
                    PictureBox image = new PictureBox();
                    image.Image = Image.FromFile(path);

                    MemoryStream mmst = new MemoryStream();
                    image.Image.Save(mmst, image.Image.RawFormat);
                    byte[] img = mmst.ToArray();

                    dataGridView.Rows.Add(bc.Barang.Id, bc.Barang.Nama, img, bc.Barang.Harga, bc.Stok, bc.Barang.Kategori.Nama);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView.DataSource = null;
            }
```

So i store the path in database and img is the image from that path.

The code works just fine but a bug is occured when there is overflow data in datagrid.

Here if there is no overflow in datagrid:
[image]

Here when the bugs occur after i scroll the data
[image]

The image from above somehow stucked in datagrid. Is there any solution to this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what… _”somehow stucked in datagrid.”_ … means. Does the grid freeze up? Does the application freeze up? What does “stucked” mean? Looking at your current code, I can only HIGHLY recommend that you avoid “manually” adding the rows to the grid. It “appears” the data is already in some collection called `listBarangCabang`… what is this list and what does it contain and is there some reason you do not use it as a `DataSource` to the grid… something like… `dataGridView.DataSource = listBarangCabang`… This should eliminate the code that manually adds the rows to the grid.

Comment: Basically, you are making this far more complicated than it has to be. Please show what `listBarangCabang` contains. I am confident you “should” be able to use that list as a `DataSource` to the grid.